# How to map file into objects with no delimiters between lines using ItemReader

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am using Spring batch's ItemReader to read a file

My input file contains long list of strings delimited by `,` looks like that:

```
2333,443445,5555,3344...
```

Each string supposed to be converted into object.

How could I  custom the ItemReader for that?

I understand that by default I can set delimiter for columns but I got only one column and my

delimiter (`,`) isn't meant to separate columns but  to separate between the records.

How could I map each string into that object:

```
public class MyItemDTO{


private String itemId;

public String getItemId() {
    return itemId;
}

public void setItemId(String itemId) {
    this.itemId= itemId;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a custom `ItemReader` in the use case you're describing.  Using the `FlatFileItemReader`, you can specify a custom `RecordSeparatorPolicy`.  By default the policy used separates by the new line character (one line = one record).  However, in your case, it would separate by `,`.  You can read more about the `RecordSeparatorPolicy` in the javadoc here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/separator/RecordSeparatorPolicy.html

Comment: Hi, I read about it but still couldnt figure it out with a working example. you mind show me any example?

Answer (score -1):

I got it working with the following `Groovy` code:

```
new FlatFileItemReader(
        resource: new FileSystemResource(filePath),
        lineMapper: new DefaultLineMapper(
                lineTokenizer: new DelimitedLineTokenizer(
                        delimiter: ',',
                        names: ['itemId']
                ),
                fieldSetMapper: new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper(
                        targetType: MyItemDTO
                )
        )
)
```

Replate `filepath` with a string that represents the path for the file you want to read.

Answer (score -1):

```
use DelimitedLineTokenizer class        
    DelimitedLineTokenizer tokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();      
    tokenizer.setDelimiter(",");          

without delimiter use FixedLengthTokenizer class    
    FixedLengthTokenizer tokenizer = new FixedLengthTokenizer();    
    tokenizer.setNames( new String[]{"val1", "val2"} );   
    tokenizer.setColumns( new Range[]{new Range( 1, 4 ),new Range( 5, 10 )} );
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!