# Reading line as String

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

My question is the somewhat related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27709580/how-to-map-file-into-objects-with-no-delimiters-between-lines-using-itemreader).

In my batch configuration I am using a flatfile reader like below with the intent to read the entire line in the flatfile as a string:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
@Qualifier("employeeItemReader")
@DependsOn("partitioner")
public FlatFileItemReader<Employee> EmployeeItemReader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext['fileName']}") String filename)
        throws MalformedURLException {
    return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<Employee>().name("employeeItemReader")
            .delimited()
            .delimiter("<#|FooBar|#>")
            //.names(new String[] { "id", "firstName", "lastName" })
            .names(new String[] { "id" })
            .fieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Employee>() {
                {
                    setTargetType(Employee.class);
                }
            })
            .linesToSkip(0)
            .resource(new UrlResource(filename)).build();
}
```

As you can see, I am using (literally) the delimiter as `.delimiter("<#|FooBar|#>")`. And it solves my purpose (in Dev environment) as I am reading a multiple files where each line contains a UUID string value. Given that my delimiter will never be present in the expected UUID.

But there are chances that there might be more than one UUID per line as I am getting those files from different sources. So, I want to tackle this situation where each line is of (similar to) this format - `afcf8f03-7d83-4c24-9b7b-d03303e70c00`.

Question: How do I make use of `FixedLengthTokenizer` to make sure I always read a line as as UUID? As I am dealing with: `8AlphNum-4AlphNum-4AlphNum-12AlphNum`. How do I tackle these alpha numerics and hyphens?

Comment: What about a step that prepares the file to have a single UUID per line before the chunk-oriented step that reads the file line by line? This would facilitate the design and implementation of the job.

Comment: Hmm.. good idea !!.. I wasn't thinking straight. Thanks.

Comment: I rather used ` @Override
 public void afterRead() {
  log.info("Data Validation And Transformation Here");
 }
`